# Webscraping form webbrowser with missing price

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Got some help but need a little more.

I am able to grab some of the information from the below script but what I am missing is the price.  The site requires a postal code (say B3K 1X2) which I put into the website then I can see the product pricing.  I am keeping that page open and opening a new page which gives me the correct product pricing.  When I run the code I get the below output.  The text "None" is suppose to be the price.  I have added the time to 60 seconds to allow the page to load all items.  Am I missing something?

***SKU
,                        ,025/BR258L40PER100(RH),,,Brand,Cambro,,,Unit of Measure,EA None***

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "D:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.russellhendrix.com/category/185/cooking-equipment?pagesize=600")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.entity-product-price-wrap.grid-item-price-wrap"))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#gv-postcalcode"))).send_keys("B3K 1X2")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.gv-red-btn.gv-set-postal"))).click()

wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.gv-red-btn.gv-set-postal")))

time.sleep(60)  # delays start of scrape for 60 secords for page to load

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
}
url = 'https://www.russellhendrix.com/category/185/cooking-equipment'
r = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')





baseurl = 'https://www.russellhendrix.com'

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://www.russellhendrix.com/category/185/cooking-equipment'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='entity-product-image-wrap')

productlinks = []

for item in productlist:
    for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
        productlinks.append(baseurl + link['href'])

for link in productlinks:
    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

    skunumber = soup.find('table', class_='product-details-table').text
    pricing = soup.find('div', class_='regPriceValue')

    print(skunumber, pricing)
```

[image]

Individual product info
https://www.russellhendrix.com/product/15388/cambro-camrack-base-rack-40p-172107a-br258l40per100rh

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I saw on several product links by opening the links manually similarly to what you do with

```
for link in productlinks:
```

There are several products that are simply missing prices.
There are no elements matching `('div', class_='gv-price')` locator.
So `soup.find('div', class_='gv-price')` will return `None` since no elements found.
**UPD**
This is the Selenium code to insert "B3K 1X2" postal code in order to get product prices:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.entity-product-price-wrap.grid-item-price-wrap"))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#gv-postcalcode"))).send_keys("B3K 1X2")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.gv-red-btn.gv-set-postal"))).click()

wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.gv-red-btn.gv-set-postal")))
```

From here you can continue with your scraping.

Comment: The gv-price element is within each individual product .  I have added an screenshot of the element to the bottom of the question.  The delay was to only allow the webpage to load with all products.

Comment: Again, I have opened several products, each on it's individual page. There is no such elements there.

Comment: I have added screenshot proof

Comment: OK, I see why you can't see it.  The site requires that you put in a postal code such as B3K 1X2 and then load the page and you should see the element.

Comment: I know, still working on that.  I wanted to see if I could get the pricing first.

Comment: But you can't... I hope I have answered your question?

Comment: Sorry no.  What do you mean I can't.  can't do what?  I know there is a way for python to add the postal code into a website, or other information for that matter.  Right now I can have the script open into a new browser in Firefox, while having a screen already opened with the postal code in it and the new screen shows the price.

Comment: With your code you can't get the prices. You can, possibly, insert the postal code and THEN you will be able to get the prices. But NOT with the code as it is currently.

Comment: ok, any clue how to do that?  Been searching for a way to do it but can't find anything that works

Comment: I can do this with Selenium, not BS. OK?

Comment: I have Selenium install so if that what is need to make it work I am ok with that.

Comment: But where can I insert the postal code there? I see only login option with predefined, existing user having defined postal code.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to the question.  The "click to view pricing" button is where you add the postal code in

Comment: I saw that. But I prefer doing this 1 time, not for each product again.

Comment: Can you not loop it?

Comment: I can login with existing user at the beginning only so this will be enough.

Comment: I appreciate your help

Comment: You know, saying "I appreciate your help" is translated here into upvoting and receiving the answer :)

Comment: OK, up voted but still working on getting it done

Comment: Can you let me know how your able to log in to the site.  I am not seeing the element to do so

Comment: Well, I see logging in not really necessary. you can insert the postal code once and after that continue with your scraping. I have updated my answer with Selenium code for setting the postal code.

Comment: Oh that works perfect.  Thank you.  I am assuming that I can continue to use BS4 to scrape the page or do I have to continue to use Selenium?

Comment: I saw people mixing both Selenium and BS4. Personally I never worked with BS4, so I don't know :0